# NOOBS randomly asking for password on startup, terminal unavailable

Tags: raspbian, noobs

I have several copies of NOOBS OS on several different microSD cards. After shutting down my Pi, taking out the card and inserting a different one, NOOBS booted to a login screen ( as you see in photo ). I tried user:root and password: raspberry and was told incorrect password. 
I found another Stack Exchange question about this issue but the answer said to run a command at the terminal. I can't open a terminal from the login screen ( or maybe I don't know how). How can I get into NOOBS and turn off this login functionality?
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Most OS's that are made for the Raspberry Pi do not have `root` as a valid username to login with (the root account is disabled). Try username `pi` with the same password, those are the default login credentials of Raspbian.

Also, NOOBS isn't an OS, it's an installer for a group of OS's. Which specific OS did you install? Raspbian?

Comment: Yes, I installed Raspbian.  However, I also tried user:pi password: raspberry and it didn't work

Comment: Did you change the password?